# Measure how diverse a dataset of point clouds is

Tags: 3d, point-cloud

I have a dataset of `N` point clouds of the same size, i.e objects represented by `M` 3d points:

```
Object 1: [(x1, y1, z1), ..., (xM, yM, zM)]
.
.
.
Object N: [(x1, y1, z1), ..., (xM, yM, zM)]
```

There are some duplications in the dataset.
I'm sampling sub-sets of from the dataset, and want to tell which sub-set has the least duplications.

How can i measure the how diverse each sub-set is?

Thanks!

Comment: you could just count the duplicates

Comment: What is your definition of "diverse" ?

Comment: Can't you just purge the whole set from its duplicates ? (This takes a sort or a hash map.)

Comment: Your question smells the XY problem...